# Can I address someone in an email with their first name if they sign with their first name?

Tags: formality, email, greetings

I'm planning to do an internship and I usually address my supervisor as Mr. X, however, he signs his emails with his first name is that means I can address him with his first name ?

Note: I haven't met him yet.(if that's makes a difference)

Comment: Yes, you can address a person the way they sign their letters (including email). In fact, people usually sign their emails the way they prefer to be addressed.

Comment: I agree more-or-less with Mr Carter. If somebody signs their e-mails <Firstname> <Lastname>, I'll address them as Mr/Ms <Lastname>. If they sign <Firstname>, then I address them as <Firstname>. At least in the case of England, I don't think there are any fixed rules about this — each person develops their own register.

Comment: I'd address them again again with his last name but sign my own email with my first name only. See if he next addresses you with your own first name.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about etiquette and protocol, with no single right answer, rather than about the English language itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is more an etiquette question than an English question, but the rule is easy enough.

**When in doubt, be consistent.**  If you would address your supervisor as "Mr. X" in person, you should do so in an email as well.  Conversely, if you would address them as "Y" in person, address them as "Y" directly as well.

It is possible that your subject may have their own particular preferences, and once those have been expressed it is good form to follow them, but until you are sure as to their preference you should err on the side of consistency.  (It would be entirely appropriate to ask them how they want to be addressed.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Regarding your first comment on what I address him in person, that's the whole point I don't know what to address him, I haven't met the guy yet. Some people have no problem with someone addressing them with their first name even if he's younger than them but how to know that?. I think I'll probably have to wait till I meet him and ask him in person.

Answer (score 2):

How someone signs off an email indicates how they want to be addressed. Hence if someone signs off with their first name *only*, this is a **clear invitation** for you to address them using their first name.

Continuing to address that person by their full name nonetheless is a sign of *insecurity* or possibly *rudeness*, and should be avoided.